# Connection refused to a server running on local network

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ubuntu, java, openjdk

I'm hosting a game server on my laptop running Ubuntu 10.04.

My friends can connect to the server completely fine, but when I try to access it, I get a "Connection refused: connect" error.
All the ports are open, but I have a feeling this has something to do with my router (Buffalo Nfiniti WHR-G300N V2).
I also cannot access an Apache server running on the laptop, although others can.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Are you using localhost, the DNS name, etc.?

Comment: If you're trying to connect to the external IP then the answer chris provided below is probably the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing via your local IP rather than the public IP/name that you provided to your friends.

Your router probably dislikes you attempting to connect to its external IP from the Internal network.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't really used stuff in the local area network before, so this came as a little "surprise" to me.